# how to auto numbering and repeat after new year in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this for my controller to auto numbering

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index (updown viewModel)
{    
    var number = db.updowns.OrderByDescending(x => x.tanggal).Select(z => z.tanggal).FirstOrDefault() ?? "00000";
    var lastPO = int.Parse(number.Substring(5, 5));
    item.tanggal = "EMOC-" + (++lastPO).ToString("00000") + "-S2/" + DateTime.Now.Year;

    db.updowns.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I want after new year, the number `00000` will repeat to `00001` again

for example record in 2016

```
EMOC-00001-S2/2016
EMOC-00002-S2/2016
EMOC-00003-S2/2016
```

and after new year will reapet the number to `00001` again like this

```
EMOC-00001-S2/2017
EMOC-00002-S2/2017
EMOC-00003-S2/2017
```

can anyone help me, please write with code too to make me more understand..

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why are you doing this what is the purpose of that property). If 2 users access your controller at the same time you would end up with duplicate values.

Comment: Just use `db.updowns.Where(x => x.[datetime_property].Year == DateTime.Now.Year).OrderByDescending(...).Select(...).FirstOrDefault() ?? "00000"`. The `Where` query will force `00000` to be incremented every year changes. However this way is prone to duplicated `tanggal` property values.

Comment: this just for example, because I new in C# and ASP. so I want to more to know, about that, I will add some Session ID for make that different @StephenMuecke

Comment: `[datetime_property]` is new table for date ? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: `Session` is not going to solve anything. The only way to do that properly would be a SQL Insert Trigger on your database table.

Comment: @Kuujoe36 No, that's a property which has `DateTime` data type in your data model. I'm sure you have a `datetime` column in DB which contains timestamp for order lists, use that to compare with current year.

Comment: I got error in `var lastPO = int.Parse(number.Substring(5, 5));` @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Either use a trigger, either use a transaction to be sure that you don't get twice the same number. As while you are calculating the last number, another request could do the same. Fix your code to filter only on the year. Using FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Year == 2017 or whatever)

Comment: can you change my code too your code to make me understand @LaurentLequenne

Comment: Thanks, my problem solved @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index (updown viewModel)
    {    
        using (var dbContextTransaction = db.BeginTransaction()) 
        { 
           var year =  DateTime.Now.Year("D4");
           var lastPO = db.updowns
               .Where(x => (x=> x.tangal.Substring(22 /* is it 22 ? */).Equals(year))
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.tanggal)
               .FirstOrDefault()?.tanggal.Substring(5, 5) ?? "00000";

           item.tanggal = "EMOC-" + (lastPO+1).ToString("00000") 
                       + "-S2/" + DateTime.Now.Year;

           db.updowns.Add(item);
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
```